# Вселенный или вселенский?

Tags: пунктуация, словообразование

**Рыбам — море, птицам — воздух, а человеку отчизна *вселенный* круг.**
Пословицы русского народа. — М.: Художественная литература В. И. Даль 1989

**Рыбам море, птицам воздух, а человеку отчизна *вселенный* круг.**
Когда Сократа (?) спросили, где его отечество, он ответил: весь свет, - считая себя жителем и гражданином всего света.
Толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона

У меня возникло два вопроса:
1. Почему в первом случае нет тире после "отчизна", а во втором случае тире вообще отсутствует?  Как правильнее?
2. Почему ***вселенный***, а не вселенский (разум,собор,заговор...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **О словах "Вселенная" и "вселенский"**

В русском языке слово «Вселенная» является заимствованием из старославянского языка «въсєленаꙗ», что является калькой древнегреческого слова «ойкумена» (др.-греч. οἰκουμένη), от глагола οἰκέω «населяю, обитаю», и в первом значении имело смысл лишь **обитаемой части мира**". [Почему слово "Вселенная" женского рода? | theqstn.com](http://theqstn.com/questions/81488/pochemu-slovo-vselennaya-zhenskogo-roda)

Можно сказать: **вселенная (обитаемая)  часть мира или вселенный (обитаемый)  круг мира**. Но в настоящее время Вселенная — это сущ. женского рода, а от   него уже образуется относительное прилагательное **"вселенский"**.

**ВСЕЛЕННАЯ**,  ж. 1. [как термин - с прописной буквы] Вся система мироздания, весь мир. 2. Вся земля, все страны. **ВСЕЛЕНСКИЙ**, 1. к Вселенная. В-ие глубины. 2. Усилит. Всемирный (1-2 зн.). В. переворот.

**2) Отсутствие тире**

**Рыбам — море, птицам — воздух, а человеку отчизна вселенный круг ( = Вселенная).**

Сравнить:

а)  Отчизна **человеку** вселенский круг. При наличии дополнения "человеку" тире не ставится. Также тире может не ставиться при инверсии, если пауза отсутствует: Человеку отчизна вселенный круг.

б) Человеку отчизна вселенный круг,   рыбам море вселенный круг, птицам воздух вселенный круг. Тире нигде не ставится, но тире ставится **в неполных предложениях** (при пропуске сочетания "вселенный круг"): рыбам — море, птицам — воздух.

Comment: Зря Вы,  SHAMPAR,  подкорректировали "шапку" моего вопроса:  я не спрашивала  "вселенный ИЛИ вселенский?",  я спрашивала  "ПОЧЕМУ вселенный?".  Смысл вопроса совершенно поменялся.  Я вижу эту разницу.  А Вы?

Comment: Сибилла, я поняла Ваш ответ так:  вселенная - это абсолютно все ВОКРУГ ( в современном восприятии), в том числе и вселенный круг, как часть, кусочек этого ВСЕГО (когда-то давно).   Тогда отнесем прилагательное  вселенный  к устаревшим, или малоупотребительным, или специфическим (как пресловутое "слиять")?      А как же "Михельсонова"  фраза без тире?   Она по пунктуации не корректна?

Comment: Да, я думаю, вселенный круг - устаревшее понятие, и в настоящее время мы пользуемся названием "Вселенная". Что касается тире, то в неполных предложениях оно во многом факультативно, то есть тире ставится при наличии паузы,  а это предложение может читаться и  с паузой,  и без паузы. Отметим, что Розенталь, рассматривая тему эллиптических и неполных предложений, обычно  в каждом правиле дополнительно указывает, что "тире ставится при наличии паузы".